# gevent and strong hashing password method

Tags: python, bcrypt, gevent

I am using gevent greenlet so I am very constrained by everything related to CPU computation. And I need to use a strong hashing method for password storage.

When I am not in a gevent context, I have the habit of using bcrypt but I did this small test :

```
import bcrypt
import time

password = b"toto"

start_hash  = time.clock()

hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

print 'time hash bcrypt %s' % (time.clock() - start_hash)

start_compare = time.clock()

assert bcrypt.hashpw(password, hashed) == hashed

elapsed = (time.clock() - start_compare)

print 'time check bcrypt %s' % elapsed
```

Which results in :

```
time hash bcrypt 0.291887
time check bcrypt 0.293343
```

This take **way too much time** to be used as it is in a greenlet.

As a comparaison, the same type of computation using the old md5 hash :

```
time hash md5 4.1e-05
time check hash md5 1.1e-05
```

What solution do I have ?

Comment: bcrypt has to be slow, because password hashes have to be slow to calculate to prevent hacking

Comment: @Daniel : I understand that. My question is more about how can I use this kind of hashing in a gevent context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gevent works well with network and IO bound functions that take advantage of concurrency but bcrypt does not have this functionality.

Try using Processlet and ObjectPool.  Processlet focuses on CPU bound tasks, like hashing, not IO bound tasks.   A great example of using bcrypt with Processlet and ObjectPool can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lets/0.0.9).

Comment: Yes but if I lower the cost factor for bcrypt or any other type of key derivation functions (argon2, ...), there won't be any real gain in using these hash methods. As I said to @Daniel, my question is really more about what can I do to not block other greenlets while this thing computes ?

Comment: Unfortunately Gevent does not allow for parallelism.  Try using a Processlet instead.  A good example of using Processlets with bcrypt is shown [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lets/0.0.9)

Comment: Interesting this processlet and there is a pool mecanism too. I will do some prototyping with that. Can you update your first answer for me to accept it ? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer.  How did that work for you @jobou?

Comment: I have not had the time to prototype it yet. Will do that next week. I will tell you my result at that time. On a side note, I have chosen the argon2 hash method. It gives great result and you can choose to optimize the computation either in time consumption or memory consumption.

Comment: I finished my test with Processlet a few days ago and It is working great. I saved a few days to not have to implement a pool myself.